# Unable to configure wso2is-5.6.0 with wso2am-2.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new working with wso2 servers.

I am following [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML)

Step2: Share the registry of both WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity Server. Refer  Sharing the registry space  for the steps.

That i am unable to get. And how to do this. And what is mean by this.

Answer (score -1):

> Step2: Share the registry of both WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity Server. Refer Sharing the registry space for the steps. 
>    That i am unable to get. And how to do this. And what is mean by this.

Sharing the registry - you may follow the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases

for both products (AM and IS):

- create a shared separate database for registry (e.g. regdb)
- configure the regdb in the master-datasources.xml
- configure registry to use the shared registry database (point 12a)

`<dbConfig name="govregistry">
      <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
    <remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
       <id>gov</id>
       <cacheId>user@jdbc:mysql://db.mysql-wso2.com:3306/regdb</cacheId>
       <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
       <readOnly>false</readOnly>
       <enableCache>true</enableCache>
       <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    </remoteInstance>
    <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
    </mount>
    <mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
    </mount>`

Comment: Which data it will store in mysql database using REG_DB

Comment: should we use only REG_DB in mysql or all DB store in MySQL

Comment: @Pankaj In configuring IS as KM you need to share WSO2_REG_DB and WSO2AM_DB and you should have the same userstore (database, ldap, AD, ..). So I advice moving all databases to mysql, it is much more reliable and manageable than the embedded h2

Comment: Have you worked on above given link access role base policy using wso2IS and wso2AM

Comment: Am unable to shared registry database or user permissions database wso2is using self permission stored in itself database

Comment: @Pankaj as you can see in the originally linked documentation, you need to share the user database between wso2am and wso2is. As far I recall, wso2is is using internal embedded ldap server by default. you can configure the same userstore in the wso2am as well

Comment: Which link are u talking